# AngularJS $q.all firing then straight away

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have an array of resources called `companies`, and I run some query calls on another resource based on that, and then fire a callback. I tried the following, but the callback gets called straight away:

```
$q.all(companies.map(function(company) {
  return Person.query({
    companyId: company.id
  });
})).then(function(people) {
  // do stuff
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OxasetGYU7xwojUNreiA?p=preview

Comment: Does `Person.query()` really return a promise? What is the value of `people` when the callback fires too early?

Comment: If you'd show us the code for `Person.query`, we could help you debugging.

Comment: @Bergi its the standard `$.resource` `query` method. I have added an example. I also tried with `$q.when` and it has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a promise array to `$q.all` to have it wait for the underlying promise(s) to be fulfilled, use the `$promise` property returned by the resource.

```
$q.all(companies.map(function(company) {
  return Person.query({
    companyId: company.id
  }).$promise; //<-- Here
})).then(function(people) {
  console.log(people);
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PEjwrRjQtYlCBcwYdzZ9?p=preview)**